# Drive name in batch

Tags: batch-file, usb, filenames, drive

I need help with a batch script.
I want one folder to sync with external usb device that has specific name (not drive letter; e.g. john's usb).
I found formula to sync folders:

```
robocopy "source folder" "destination folder" /e /purge
```

Source folder is not problem because it's specific folder on my drive but destination folder should be external usb with specific name (e.g. John's usb).
I can't do this using drive letters because sometimes I have more than 1 usb sticks connected in PC.
Hope someone can help.
Regards

Comment: If the batch file is stored on the USB stick `%~d0` can be used inside the batch file instead of `D:`, `E:`, etc. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for help on how to reference batch file arguments like argument 0 which is the batch file name of currently running batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the correct drive letter:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:=" %%a in (`wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName^="John's usb" get caption /value`) do set drive=%%a:
if "%drive%"=="" (
  echo not inserted
) else (
  echo inserted as %drive%
)
```

Comment: You could alternatively use [`Win32_Volume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx#) with `Label` and `DriveLetter` instead of [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx#).

Comment: Thx Stephan, your answer helps me a lot.
Regards